# Showing network traffic status in system tray?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04, notification-area

I can't find a way to show network traffic status (especially download) in Ubuntu gnome system tray. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution: Indicator-Sysmonitor
https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor

And then followed this tutorial:
But had to change the ppa to this one: https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```